# Is it possible to simplify the definition of Cont with RankNTypes?

Tags: haskell, continuations

I'm reading [this implementation](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-14.6/transformers-0.5.6.2/Control-Monad-Trans-Cont.html) of Continuation in Haskell, and find it tricky, most of the time, `r` is not such important, so we provide `reset` to make it easy to be replaced.

So I think the `r` type variable in `Cont r a` is not necessary to be exposured, maybe we can just use `forall r` to hide `r` inside the definition of `Cont` at all, so following is my try:

```
{-# language RankNTypes #-}

data Cont a = MkCont {runCont :: forall r. (a -> r) -> r}

-- try to construct a Cont
c1 :: Cont Int
c1 = MkCont ($ 1)

evalCont :: Cont a -> a
evalCont c = runCont c id

-- mapCont is useless since `f` can only be `id` now
mapCont :: (forall r. r -> r) -> Cont a -> Cont a
mapCont f c = (MkCont (f . runCont c))

withCont :: (forall r. (b -> r) -> a -> r) -> Cont a -> Cont b
withCont f c = MkCont (runCont c . f)

-- reset is unnecessary since `r` is hidden
reset :: Cont a -> Cont a
reset = id

shift :: (forall r. (a -> r) -> Cont r) -> Cont a
shift f = MkCont (evalCont . f)

-- don't know how to define `callCC` now ...
callCC :: ((a -> Cont b) -> Cont a) -> Cont a
callCC = undefined  -- this definition seems impossible to implement
```

But I got a problem when trying to define and implement callCC, if I reference the traditional definition, then it should be

```
callCC f = MkCont $ \c1 -> runCont (f (\x -> MkCont $ \c2 -> c1 x)) c1
```

But the above code doesn't type check, so did I make some stupid mistake, or it is impossible to define `Cont` like this?

PS: I'm not sure above type of `callCC` is the proper one of my definition of `Cont`, maybe it need some adjust.

Answer (score 0):

This monad (transformer) is also called `Codensity`: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/kan-extensions-5.2/docs/Control-Monad-Codensity.html

---

You haven't actually implemented `reset` either, there's more to it than the types. The following equation must be satisfied:

> ```
> reset (shift f >>= k) = reset (f (evalCont . k))
> ```
>
> -- https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.6.2/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Cont.html#v:shift